# I set up my Digital Ocean server for Laravel 5 with NGINX, why do i get Laravel: command not found?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean

Disclaimer: I am completely new to laravel and setting up my own development server.

I set up a Laravel environment on my digital ocean server with Nginx (followed this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-an-nginx-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)

When i try to run Laravel commands like "Laravel new applicationName" i get just get Laravel: command not found.

Am i missing something?

Comment: You are supposed to run the laravel command when creating a new laravel project. I strongly suggest you do this locally (preferably on laravels own dev vm homestead). Then use your vps for demos/testing/production

Comment: You can use composer installation

Comment: Did you run `composer global require "laravel/installer"` as showcased in the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2#installing-laravel)? Otherwise you can't use the Laravel installer, because the tutorial you referenced only explains how to install Laravel using `composer create-project ...`.

Comment: ahhh that makes sense @Bogdan will try it, otherwise ill run a Homestead instance.